# Stored images limit per entry - Channel Images

Tags: ee2, devdemon, channel-images

I have an entry with 125 images in a channel images field.

Since the website is multi-linugal, a related entry needs to have the same number of images.

However, the limit of stored images seem to be 50.

How can we have all the stored images for a related entry.

And also it would be great if there was an add all images and remove all images button.

Am using EE 2.11.9 and Channel Images 5.4.19

Answer (score 1):

For the channel images field where you're hitting the limit, go to the field settings:

Channel Fields > Your_field > Fieldtype Settings (tab) > Image Limit

and set as blank for unlimited images.

Comment: In my case I have the Image Limit field empty and it's still showing just 30 images from 50. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

By default Channel Image show first 30 images. If you want to display all of them you need to set a limit higher than your total number of images.

[See Doc - limit](http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/tag/images/)

> limit -   This parameter limits the number of images on any given page.
>   The limit will default to 30 entries if a value is not specified. If
>   you are using pagination then this will determine the number of
>   entries shown per page.

Example:

```
{exp:channel_images:images limit="100"}
{image:title}
{/exp:channel_images:images}
```